# How to vectorize the pow function (with negative bases)?

Tags: c++, c, sse, avx, pow

I'm trying to vectorize (SSE/AVX) the pow function. In all implementations that I have found, it simply vectorized using `log` and `exp`:

```
pow(x, y) = exp(y * log(x))
```

It works well for positive x, but this won't work for negative `x` since the log of a negative number is a complex number. Is it possible to efficiently vectorize the pow while keeping the ability to handle negative `x` numbers ?

Comment: Write a wrapper by yourself.

Comment: Do you know the algorithm to get the complex number from a negative number? If not then first try to find out that. Then implement it in a non-vectorized way. Test it, make sure it works. Then attempt to vectorize it.

Comment: Are either `x` or `y` known to be integers?

Comment: pow() has a complex result for negative powers.  Except in the special case of the power being an integral value or infinity.  Vectorizing such a test is not meaningful.

Comment: @AlanStokes No, not necessarily, I'd like to support both cases.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the only solution is use a conditional and then use the complex result. I know how to compute it, but it won't be very efficient :s

Answer (score 5):

This is a generic answer that doesn't take advantage of any specifics of how you might actually vectorize pow().

---

You could check if any of the elements of the base-vector are negative, and branch on that to select between a fast path and a slow path.

Return two vectors, of real parts and imaginary parts, so the fast path can return `_mm_setzero_ps()` for the imaginary part.  Callers that don't want the imaginary part can ignore it (instead of having to shuffle to extract the real part for vectors of alternating real/imaginary).

So callers that pass only non-negative bases get behaviour that's nearly as fast as a vectorized real-only version.

But callers that pass a mix of negative and non-negative will get the slow version.  If you can vectorize the slow version, that's perfect.

If it doesn't work for positive bases, when there's a mix you could run both and blend (based on the same compare-mask that you checked to see if you needed the slow version).

For an AVX version, type an extra `256` into the intrinsic names.  (And change the check to `== 0xff`, because you have 4 more bits in the movemask result).

```
// SSE4.1 for BLENDVPS
__m128  pow_complexresult(__m128 base, __m128 exp, __m128 &imag_result)
{
    __m128 negbase_vec = _mm_cmplt_ps(base, _mm_setzero_ps());
    unsigned negbase_mask = _mm_movemask_ps(negbase_vec);

    if (negbase_mask == 0) {               // all elements false
        imag_result = _mm_setzero_ps();
        return pow_nonegative(base, exp);   // fast path
    } else if (negbase_mask == 0xf) {      // all elements true
        return pow_negative(base, exp, imag_result);
    } else {
        // Only needed if pow_negative doesn't work for non-negative inputs.
        __m128 negpow = pow_negative(base, exp, imag_result);
        __m128 pospow = pow_simple(base, exp);
        imag_result = _mm_andn_ps(negbase_mask, imag_result);  // blend imaginary part
        return _mm_blendv_ps(pospow, negpow, negbase_vec);  // blend real part
    }
}
```

Make sure the helper functions inline so you aren't really passing a vector by reference through memory.

And/or inline this wrapper into the callers, which may let the check optimize away for constant vectors.

I don't think either Windows or System V ABIs will return a struct of two `__m256` vectors in two `ymm` registers, so a 2nd by-reference arg is probably the best you're going to get.

Notice that `imag_result` is the last arg, so even in the Windows x64 ABI, this function can still forward its args in the same registers to `pow_nonegative(base, exp);`.  Although you want it to inline anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do some arithmetic with negative numbers, you can use the principal branch of `log()` function, that introduces an imaginary `+i*b*pi` number to the result, which translates then in a `exp(+i*b*pi)` factor..... that maps to real only in the cases your exponent `b` is an exact integer number..... this is not the general case you have, as the function `pow(3)` is declared for `double` type.... you can solve this issue, writing a wrapper function that checks for negative first parameter, and gives a negative also only in case the second parameter is an odd integer number.  The implementation details are hidden as an exercise for you to complete... is quite easy to implement a `double generalized_pow(double b, double e);` that does this checking and gives the appropiate result.

But if the exponent `b` parameter is going to be integer... then you have better to implement the [*fast power algorithm*](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~mcs171/Fa09/notes/07.3_recursion_intro/fastPower.html?CurrentSlide=5), that will give you the answer probably faster than going through the `exp(3)` and `log(3)` functions.  Look in Google for an implementation of the fast exponential algorithm.

Comment: The trick is doing this *efficiently* when the SIMD vector of 4 bases and 4 exponents might contain a mix of cases.  You can check if all the exponents are already exact integers with `_mm_cmpeq_ps(exp, _mm_round_ps(e, 0 /*nearest*/))`, and if that's common in your code then it might be worth checking for.  But more likely it only happens in cases that are known at compile time, so you should just write a `powi` function that takes an integer vector of powers.  Or a vector of FP values that are guaranteed to be integers.